# Python- Saving list of objects and its attributes

Tags: python, list, object

I am trying to save a list of objects and its corresponding attributes that go along with it. In the following example you can see that I first, define the list of objects and attributes, and then save it. Once the file has been saved, I delete the list to show that it is empty, but when I call the loading function, my list remains blank. Does anyone know why ?

```
import pickle

class Company(object):
    def __init__(self, name, value):
        self.name = name
        self.value = value

class Define_Companies():

    company_list = []

    def run_this(self):

        for x,y in enumerate(range(0,6)):
            company_list_object = Company(x,y)
            Define_Companies().company_list.append(company_list_object)


        for x in Define_Companies().company_list:
            print(x.name)

Define_Companies().run_this()

def save_this_information():

    with open('company_data.pkl', 'wb') as output:
        pickle.dump(Define_Companies().company_list, output, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)

Define_Companies().company_list.clear()
save_this_information()

def load_the_information():

    with open('company_data.pkl', 'rb') as input:
        Define_Companies().company_list = pickle.load(input)
    print(Define_Companies().company_list)

load_the_information()
```

Output:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
[]
```

Comment: You shouldn't instantiate new instances of `Define_Companies()` inside of your class definition of `Define_Companies`

Comment: I made the changes, but that didn't change the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call `Define_Companies().company_list.clear()` right before your save function, which clears all elements in the list.
You are trying to save an empty list.

---

Also note that you don't need to have an instance of `Define_Companies` to access the class variable `company_list` because it is bound to the class, not an instance. to access the list you can just type `Define_Companies.company_list`.